# Style the first legend element within a nested fieldsets

Tags: css, legend, fieldset

I'm trying to style the first `legend` element within nested fieldsets, but none of the CSS selectors I used achieve what I'm after.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epodxd

I basically want to style the first legend element without using any additional CSS class if possible.

```
<fieldset class="nested-parent">
    <legend>Parent</legend>
    <input type="text" size="10" />

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Child</legend>
        <input type="text" size="20" />
    </fieldset>
</fieldset>
```

```
.nested-parent legend:first-child {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the HTML you provided, you could use the [child selector, `>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#child-selectors) in order to select the first `legend` element that is a direct child of the `.nested-parent` element:

```
.nested-parent > legend:first-child {
  color: #f00;
}
```

I would suggest using the [`:first-of-type` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Afirst-of-type) instead though. It will be more accurate when dealing with the element's types.

[**Example Here**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojOzVq)

```
.nested-parent > legend:first-of-type {
  color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: A legend can only be the first child of a fieldset in a valid HTML document anyway, so whether you use :first-child or :first-of-type probably isn't going to make a difference (unless you're dealing with invalid markup). But the key here is to use a child selector with the specific fieldset whose child legend you're targeting.

Comment: @BoltClock Ah, good point. I didn't know that! I guess this will just cover cases where there is invalid markup then..

Comment: Thanks a lot, Josh and BoltClock!